# Has anyone been able to deploy a Django project to elasticbeanstalk by uploading a zip file?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, deployment, zip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been able to deploy django projects using:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html , which is deployment from terminal on my mac.
But I haven’t been able to do it by uploading a zip file. “ebdjango” is the name of my project.
**django.config** contains:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: ebdjango.wsgi:application
```

requirements.txt contains:

```
asgiref==3.7.2
Django==4.2.9
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.9.0
```

I am not sure if there is something wrong with how I create the zip file because i get the warning message: “Configuration files cannot be extracted from the application version ebdjango. Check that the application version is a valid zip or war file.”
What I do is I compress **.ebextensions**, **ebdjango** **manage.py** and **requirements.txt** . When I open the zip file there is a root folder with the same name as the zip file and that folder contains **.ebextensions**, **ebdjango** **manage.py** and **requirements.txt** . Is it supposed to be like that or is everything supposed to be extracted from the zip when i open it without a parent folder? Is this why I can’t deploy my django project to elasticbeanstalk?